# Why am I unable to add elements into a LinkedList in Java?

Tags: java

This is part of a lab I couldn't figure out... I can't figure out what is wrong in the addGrade method in the roster class, where I have to add a grade to a student, and if the student doesn't already exist, create a new student and then add the grade. Note that initially, this class didn't have the instance variable Student stu, which I added when trying to get things to work.

Student is provided with a constructor, student scores are saved in a linkedlist. I only put a part of the code here... it has methods to get student name, get score, add score, and get score average.

My code is no longer working after some edits... when it was partially working, it just overwrote the previous students with the latest one. Student a was added with grade 5, then student b with 7, then student a is added again with 10. This should have student a with 2 entries (5, 10) in the linkedlist. When I ran my code it only had student a with 10, but also didn't work completely.

```
public class Student {
private String name;
private List scores = new LinkedList<>();

  public Student(String name)
  {
     this.name = name;
  }

  public void addGrade(int score)
  {
     scores.add(score);
  }


public class Roster {

String name;
int score;
Student stu;

   //Adds a grade to the end of a list of grades for the named student.
   //Should work even if no student with this name has ever been seen before.
   public void addGrade(String name, int score) {
       Student temp = new Student(name);
       stu.addGrade(score);
   }
    //Gets the specified grade from the named student's scores.
   public int getGrade(String name, int index) {
       int a = stu.getScore(index);
       return a;
   }
    //Gets the average for the named student.
   public double getAverage(String name) {
       return stu.getAverage();
   }
}
```

Comment: So let's start with a definition of "working".  What does code that works behave like?  What part specifically is causing you the trouble?

Comment: You probably want a `List` of `Student` in `Roster` (or it's a 1-guy class :p). Note that a `Map` using student name as key and student as value might be handy here (easier to check for existing student).

Comment: And you probably want a `Map<String, Integre> scores` instead of a linked-list (mapping a course to a score).

Answer (score 1):

A roster is a list of students.

A student has a list of scores.

This is not all of the code you will need, just part of your Roster class and the `addGrade()` method there:

```
public class Roster {
    List<Students> students = new LinkedList<Student>();

    public void addGrade(String name, int score) {
        // Student s = null;
        // Search for existing student.
        for (Student currentStu : students) {
            if (currentStu.name.equals(name) {
                s = currentStu;
            }
        }

        if (s == null) {
            //Student not in our roster. Add him.
            s = new Student(name);
        }

        // Add the score to that student.
        s.addGrade(score);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of things going on with this code, but I'll give you some pointers on what could be going wrong.  I strongly encourage you to reach out to your teacher, a tutor or a TA to close the loop on some things, but for the most part, here are some of the conceptual errors that I see.

- A Student is the most basic piece of information.  A Roster contains a collection of students.  It is likely the case that you want a `List<Student>` in your Roster class.  You don't require any other fields than that in Roster.

  You should provide a way to add more scores to a specific student, but this particular aspect I'll leave for you to discuss with your teacher.
- Your current linked list declaration of scores is untyped.  This is frowned upon since you will generate unchecked warnings at compile time, and if you accidentally add a non-numeral into that linked list, you'll get an error at runtime when attempting to do math on it.

  It's also interesting that you use a linked list instead of an array-backed list, since you intend to index into the list.  For performance reasons, I would recommend using `ArrayList`.

  With all of that said, you would want to type it as `List<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<>()`.
- You need a way to search for a student by name.  This is a bit tricky since you're storing `Student` entries in there, but it can be done.  I'll describe a very rudimentary approach to it, but I want you to take it from there:

  - Iterate over the collection of all students you have in your roster.
  - If a student's name matches the current instance, then you've found your student.
  - If there is no student contained in the list that has the name, then you have to return a number that represents that there is no student there.  0 would be bad for averages as you *can* have an average score of 0; perhaps -1 would work.

Comment: Returning '0', or '-1' if a student is not found is an antipattern.  This is Java, not C.  Use a Map.  Calling that an over optimisation is quite odd.

Comment: I would personally not want to do that, but I don't believe that the student has progressed far enough to understand the implications of throwing an exception.  I'd ***really*** rather they reached out to their teacher instead of us, since we're more or less well-versed in good practices and years of experience, but since I haven't provided concrete code (and only suggestions), I'm not too bothered about the suggestion.

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, they'll read up an on what an Exception is and learn something.  I would like to give them that chance. Thanks for the downvote...

Answer (score 0):

A `Map<String,Student>` is the key here:

```
public class Roster {
    private final Map<String, Student> students = new HashMap<>();

    //Adds a grade to the end of a list of grades for the named student.
    //Should work even if no student with this name has ever been seen before.
    public void addGrade(String name, int score) {
        Student stu = students.get(name);
        if (stu == null) {
            stu = new Student(name);
            students.put(name, stu);
        }
        stu.addGrade(score);
    }

    //Gets the specified grade from the named student's scores.
    public int getGrade(String name, int index) {
        Student student = students.get(name);
        if (student == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Student not found: " + name);
        }
        return student.getScore(index);
    }

    //Gets the average for the named student.
    public double getAverage(String name) {
        Student student = students.get(name);
        if (student == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Student not found: " + name);
        }
        return student.getAverage();
    }
}
```

Comment: A map stores redundant information in the form of the student name.  It's a good optimization but not wholly necessary for this particular exercise.

Comment: How do you know what the requirements are for the exercise?

Comment: I don't.  But I could tell you that if a Map were needed, a Map would be used instead of a List, since that's how these sorts of exercises work.